# Scrapy Iteration issue in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, scrapy

I am having some issues with Scrapy, I was using the newcoder tutorial and seem to be getting stuck with iteration. 
**Tutorial Here**
http://newcoder.io/scrape

I am trying to scrape: http://freefuninaustin.com/

I am able to get all the titles with ease using :
            'title': '//h3[@class="content-list-title"]//@title'

However whenever I run the scraper, it gets ALL the titles for each of the posts and inputs them into my database.. I want it to pull just one title for each post and input into the database.

Code from the spider itself:

```
deals_list_xpath = '//article'
item_fields = {
    'title': '//h3[@class="content-list-title"]//@title'

def parse(self, response):
    """
    Default callback used by Scrapy to process downloaded responses

    Testing contracts:
    @url http://www.freefuninaustin.com/blog/
    @returns items 1
    @scrapes title 

    """
    selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    # iterate over deals
    for deal in selector.xpath(self.deals_list_xpath):
        loader = XPathItemLoader(LivingSocialDeal(), selector=deal)

        # define processors
        loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
        loader.default_output_processor = Join()

        # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
        for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
            loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
        yield loader.load_item()
```

And now the pipeline

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    """Save deals in the database.

    This method is called for every item pipeline component.

    """
    session = self.Session()
    deal = Deals(**item)

    try:
        session.add(deal)
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

    return item
```

And the results from scrapy

```
     loader = XPathItemLoader(LivingSocialDeal(), selector=deal)
2015-05-10 20:56:49-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://freefuninaustin.com/blog/>
    {'title': u'Austin Area Splash Pads \u2013 2015 Schedules Reader Recommended: Favorite Parks in Austin and Beyond What\u2019s Up? Weekly (May 11-15, 2015) Weekend Top 10 FREE Events (May 8-10, 2015) Free Deutschen Pfest Parade in Pflugerville 2nd Annual Art in the Park in Round Rock Free Date Nights in Austin (May 7-10, 2015) Mother\u2019s Day Events & Freebies in Austin West Austin Studio Tour 2015 Picks for Families DIY Learning: O. Henry Museum Giveaway: Austin Children\u2019s Services Touch-A-Truck'}
2015-05-10 20:56:49-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://freefuninaustin.com/blog/>
    {'title': u'Austin Area Splash Pads \u2013 2015 Schedules Reader Recommended: Favorite Parks in Austin and Beyond What\u2019s Up? Weekly (May 11-15, 2015) Weekend Top 10 FREE Events (May 8-10, 2015) Free Deutschen Pfest Parade in Pflugerville 2nd Annual Art in the Park in Round Rock Free Date Nights in Austin (May 7-10, 2015) Mother\u2019s Day Events & Freebies in Austin West Austin Studio Tour 2015 Picks for Families DIY Learning: O. Henry Museum Giveaway: Austin Children\u2019s Services Touch-A-Truck'}
2015-05-10 20:56:49-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://freefuninaustin.com/blog/>
    {'title': u'Austin Area Splash Pads \u2013 2015 Schedules Reader Recommended: Favorite Parks in Austin and Beyond What\u2019s Up? Weekly (May 11-15, 2015) Weekend Top 10 FREE Events (May 8-10, 2015) Free Deutschen Pfest Parade in Pflugerville 2nd Annual Art in the Park in Round Rock Free Date Nights in Austin (May 7-10, 2015) Mother\u2019s Day Events & Freebies in Austin West Austin Studio Tour 2015 Picks for Families DIY Learning: O. Henry Museum Giveaway: Austin Children\u2019s Services Touch-A-Truck'}
2015-05-10 20:56:49-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://freefuninaustin.com/blog/>
```

**This is how it should look**

```
2015-05-10 21:13:55-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco>
    {'title': u'1 or 3 Private Golf Lessons'}
2015-05-10 21:13:55-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco>
    {'title': u'Los Angeles Dodgers at Oakland Athletics on August 18'}
2015-05-10 21:13:55-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco>
    {'title': u'Glycolic or Salicylic Glow Facial Peel'}
2015-05-10 21:13:55-0500 [livingsocial] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco>
    {'title': u'Boston Red Sox at Oakland Athletics on May 11'}
```

How can I go about extracting the title only once per post?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.` (dot) at the beginning of XPath expression to make it "context-specific":

```
item_fields = {
    'title': './/h3[@class="content-list-title"]//@title'
}
```

There are also different "types" of `article` elements on the page and to handle both, you need to rewrite your expression to:

```
.//h3[@class="content-list-title" or @class="cp-title-small"]//@title
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try once I get home.